# How to use date filter in custom filter in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

i have created one custom filter which is wrapper on date filter.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    app.filter('localiseDate', function ($filter,$locale) {
        return function (val, args) {
            var dateFormat, date;
            if (Date.parse(val)) {
                date = new Date(val);
                if (args) {
                    dateFormat = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS[args] ? $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS[args] : args;
                }
                else {
                    dateFormat = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.shortDate;
                }
                date = $filter('date')(date, dateFormat);
            }
            else {
                date = val;
            }
            return date;
        };

    });
}())
```

when ever i tried to use this filter in service and in view it showing me following error

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…l%3A%20%5C%2210.09.14%5C%22%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%5C%2209.10.14%5C%22%22%5D%5D
```

it look like when i will apply filter rootScope goes infinite loop
how to use date filter within custom filter? or how to avoid this infinite looping?

Comment: It must be another issue because your filter works. Anymore context?

Comment: @Dting but if use $.datepicker.formatDate to format date then it's work fine. only it show error with angukar date filter

Comment: Can you show an example of the code that is using localiseDate thats throwing it in a infdig loop? Also check code for any $watch that are on the date vars?